# Why can a global list be modified in a function without using the keyword global?

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

[image]

The code above is reasonable to me, as I know it is necessary to use the keyword `global` to assign or modify a global variable.

[image]

However, when I am using a list, I can access the global variable without using the keyword `global`. Does that mean whether using global depends on the type of a variable? Do I need to use global when assigning or modifying other types of variable (tuple, dic, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

When we assign a variable inside a function, that variable is local by default.
Now if we see what's happening in pr() function a is assigned as:
**a += 1 i.e. a = a + 1.**

When python reaches/scans this line of code, it sees left side a first and then puts in it's local scope. When it sees right side a then finds there is no value assigned to a(which became local variable). That's why it throws error.

On the other hand, list is mutable (changeable in-place) object. That's why assignment doesn't matter in case of mutable objects (list or dictionary).

Also string is immutable so it is treated differently during assignment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).